# Too many initializer values in array assignment

Tags: c++

I'm doing Sierpinski carpet using recursion.
In function DrawCarpet in linen, where I redefine a value I got error "To many initializer values". Do somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
typedef float point[2];

float x = 100;
float y = 100;
point a = {  x , y  };
int grade = 4;

void DrawCarpet(point a, GLfloat width, GLfloat grade)
{


    if(grade>0)
    {


        width = width / 3;

        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = {  x - width , y };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = {  x - 2*width , y  };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = {  x , y-width  };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a =  { x  , y-2*width  };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = {  x - width , y-width  };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = {  x - width , y -2*width };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = {  x -2* width , y -2*width };
        DrawCarpet(a, width, grade - 1);
        a = { x,y };

    } 
}
```

Comment: Please 1) post a [mcve]. 2) post the actual error message you get (*verbatim*).

Comment: You cannot assign an array.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays.  All of your `a =` lines in the function are assignment, not initialization.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::array<float, 2>` instead of `float[2]`?

Answer (score 1):

The type of parameter `a` is not *array of 2 `float`* but rather `float*` (because of [array to pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay), also because your function parameter shadows the global variable). So what you're trying to do is assign two values to a pointer variable. Try using a struct with two members as a point type instead, and pass that by reference if you want to assign to it.